# Spring-data Mongo not creating outputCollection after mapReduce operation

Tags: spring, mongodb, mapreduce, spring-data

Consider the following code snippet-

```
 MapReduceResult<CookiesResult> result = mongoTemplate.mapReduce(
                "cookies",
                cookieMapFn,
                cookieResultFn,
                new MapReduceOptions().outputCollection("cookiesMapReduced"),
                CookiesResult.class
);

return mongoTemplate.find(new Query(new Criteria("cookies").gte(5)),
                          CookiesResult.class, "cookiesMapReduced").iterator();
```

I'm able to run this MapReduce operation, and even get the results I expect in the result variable.  I'm confident there is nothing wrong with the actual semantics of the MapReduce Query I am running.

However I need to have this result stored into a temporary collection "cookiesMapReduced" but the driver does not seem to be creating the collection?  From the spring documentation It seems like I've set up everything to have the results written to a collection instead of "inline" (`{out: {inline : 1}}`)

Is there something in the MapReduceOptions I'm missing?  I've tried also setting the outputDatabase but according to the [documentation's example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mapreduce.example) all I should need to set is `outputCollection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the collection not being created is a bug in Spring-data Mongo 2.0.8.  It is fixed in 2.0.10, and will now process the MapReduceOptions Object.

For more information, you can check out DATAMONGO-2027 on https://jira.spring.io/